# HSTS Implementation and response type

Tags: tls, hsts

I have implemented the HSTS in my ASP.Net MVC based Website. But if I make a HTTP(not HTTPS) request, the request is propagating using the HTTP channel and the response is 301: Moved Permanently. And from the 2nd request onwards, it is communicating using HTTPS.

Is this the correct behavior of HSTS ? I am bit concerned about, if someone deliberately request for http traffic is it still accepting it (the first request).

Comment: The browser can only pick up the HSTS header after the first visit (if it's not preloaded). So that's exactly the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called TOFU(Trust On First Use) along with HSTS. You need add your URL to the [HSTS Preload List](https://hstspreload.org/) to enable your first request with HSTS. It is checking your HSTS attributes such as  max-age and includeSubDomains etc... and adds your site to the list if it compliance.

You can check existing HSTS enabled site list in the [chromium project git](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json). You can load one of these correctly implemented HSTS sites and check how those are behaving.

You can check the browser (chrome) related HSTS settings using this [url](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts)

Comment: What you wrote about 301 vs. 307 is wrong: there is no performance  or security improvement since in both cases the response containing the code is still send to the browser which then creates a new HTTP request to the new target. The main difference is that 307 definitely does not change the request method whereas the semantics with 301/302 are not clear. Apart from that 307 is a temporary redirect (not *internal* like you've stated) compared to 301 being a permanent redirect - the last being more appropriate since compared to 302/307 the browser will not retry the original URL later.

Comment: Thanks for the update guys. i think I better add my site to the preload list first.

Comment: @Steffan: Thanks for the update mate ! I have updated the answer.